# Can't clone sword into player backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

Im trying to clone a sword from replicated storage into all players who are in the round's backpack backpack.

code:

```
for i, v in pairs(game.Workspace.PlayerInRound:GetChildren()) do
local sword = game.ReplicatedStorage.ClassicSword:Clone()
sword.Parent = game.Players.v.Backpack
end
```

but it just says v is not part of players.

Comment: What are the children in the `game.Workspace.PlayerInRound` folder? Are they StringValues? Are they the Character models of the Players themselves?

Answer (score 0):

`sword.Parent = game.Players.v.Backpack` is the same as `sword.Parent = game.Players['v'].Backpack`, which is definitely senseless. Since `v` is an object, perhaps, you need `sword.Parent = v.Backpack`.

Comment: While this is the correct line to address the issue, this answer assumes that `v` is a `Player` object, which is unlikely considering that the array of objects being iterated over came from a folder in the Workspace, not `game.Players`.

Answer (score 0):

What script are you using?

**----Local Script**

```
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    Sword.Parent = player.BackPack
```

**----Script**

```
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
       Sword.Parent = player.Backpack
   end)
```